# How to route array signal to input

Tags: vhdl

I have a top-level VHDL module that includes a signal that I declare to be an array of unsigned numbers. I have an instantiated component within this top-level module, and I want to route the array in the top-level module to this component. Making the same declaration of

```
type array_type is array(5 downto 0) of unsigned (15 downto 0);
```

in the component doesn't seem to work. I already know how to connect inputs to outputs containing arrays, but I'm not sure how to connect a signal to an input/output.

EXAMPLE TOP-LEVEL MODULE

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity top_level is
end top_level;

architecture str_arch of top_level is
   type array_type is array (5 downto 0) of unsigned (15 downto 0);
   signal example_array: array_type;
begin
instantiated_component: entity work.component(Behavioral)
   port map(array=>example_array);
end str_arch;
```

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.2 Type declarations, para 3: "The types created by the elaboration of distinct type definitions are distinct types. ...". There is enough information present to determine that the actual `example_array` has a distinct type definition not available to the entity declaration for `component`.  As sligor answers shared declarations are placed in packages made visible by use clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) declaring somewhere:

```
type array_type is array(5 downto 0) of unsigned (15 downto 0);
```

and in another place:

```
type array_type is array(5 downto 0) of unsigned (15 downto 0);
```

**declares two different types** ! even if they have the same name (they will  have a full extended name: somewhere.array_type and another.array_type )

2) VHDL is a strongly typed language and even if the two different "types" you declared have the same definition you can't assign one to another.

One easy solution is to use the **same type** (from a package):

```
package pkg is
  type array_type is array(5 downto 0) of unsigned (15 downto 0);
end package pkg;
```

And in the sub-module and to-level modules:

```
use work.pkg.all; --if pkg is in the same library
```